# Reading text in Text box after hitting enter C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keydown, enter

I have a simple requirment in C# WPF. I got a textbox in which I will enter some text. When I press Enter, I want an event to be fired.  My code is

```
 private void AddKeyword(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
      {
         //DO something
      }
  }
```

I have set my Textbox AcceptReturn =True; The Method is simply not working and I dont see any event fired when I press Enter. Please Help me out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: is AddKeyword subscribed to KeyUp event?

Comment: Yes.. AddKeyword is Subscribed to KeydDown event. Other keys are firing events. Only When I press Enter it stays Idle. Instead of an event firing, It starts a new line of text in textbox

Comment: share your codes pls, will help to find issue!

Comment: key up is different from key down try using keyup like the response by @AppDeveloper

Answer (score 2):

This work fine for me

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" KeyUp="textBox1_KeyUp" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Enter Fired!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```